# How to change only variable color in a print label

Tags: swift3

I want change a color only for variable in a tuple print like this

```
result.text = ("\(var1) candy  " + " of: \(var2) blablabla")
```

Now, how can I change color of "var1" and "var2", from the inspector I set red color for the label, but it's impossible change color only for variable.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: I try but it's not easy way, required range position for modify color, I need to set only the var1 and var2 in different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is create an attributed string for each color (let's say blue and yellow):

```
let t : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hi", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue])

let t2 : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: " There", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.yellow])
```

If you want to join them together:

```
let final = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: t)

final.append(t2)
```

**UPDATE**

so in your case, since you want to color two different sections of your resulting string, you'd want to use the NSRange approach. So a method like this:

```
func colorTheVariables(_ var1Value: String,_ var2Value: String) {

        let middle = " candy of: ".characters.count

        let value = "\(var1Value) candy of : \(var2Value)"

        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: value)

        let range1 = NSRange(location: 0, length: var1Value.characters.count)
        let range2 = NSRange(location: range1.length + middle, length: var2Value.characters.count)

        text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: var1Color, range: range1)
        text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: var2Color, range: range2)

        result.attributedText = text
    }
```

Should give you the coloring you want for var1 and var 2. It's important you apply text to `attributedText` of the label, not to text. Printing `result.text` should give you the content of the label, but printing `result.attributedText` will give you the weird nsAttributed string print.

Comment: I try but not work, in a label print first value like this 10{ always red color like set in inspector. I don't understand. I write de code directly in button action. I modify for my code, but nothing. not print a value

Comment: debug area

-144.00{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1";
}
5.0{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1";
}
--------------
-144.00
5.0

Comment: Did it help you?